# Jquery autocomplete with Dynamic input box.?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I  have  done  so  much  R & D for  Jquery  Auto complete, I found  some  result  but  not  as  much  i  needed.  I  am  giving  you  code  which  are  currently i am using .

```
    <ul>
         @foreach (var items in Model)
            {
             <li class="@items.ShortDesc" id="@items.ShortDesc">
                <div class="test0">             
                @Html.TextBox(@items.ShortDesc, @items.SfldDefault, new { @class = "catalog inputcatalog txtbox" })          
                                </div>  
                        </li>

                    }
                </ul> This  input  box will  created  by  Dynamic using forloop
```

// My Jquery Code

```
     $(function () {
    $("#Subject").autocomplete({
        source: '/Cataloging/Bib/GetSubject',
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // Do something with "ui.item.Id" or "ui.item.Name" or any of the other properties you selected to return from the action
        }
    });
});
```

//  My Action  Method

```
  public ActionResult GetSubject(string term)
    {
         term = term.Substring(2, term.Length-2);

        return Json(db.BibContents.Where(city => city.Value.StartsWith(term)).Select(city => city.Value), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

// My code  is  running  with  static  input  but  while  creating  Dynamic  I  need  to  use  live  event but  i  don't  know  how  can  i  use  Live Event  with this code.

NOTE:  I  am  using  static  value of  input  "|a"  after  rendering  on action i am removing that first two char to make proper search from database.
Thanks

Comment: which plugin are you using ?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya - .autocomplete comes with jQuery UI

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: your forloop is a javascript forloop or php forloop ?

Comment: i  am  using  .Net MVC  Razor forloop

Comment: @KapsHasija - when debugging is that return line getting a good json result??

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya  I  need  "|a" this  kind  of  requirement

Comment: If the inputs are going to be created dynamically, just give all the inputs the same class instead of binding it using the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to make the same class for all txtboxes

```
    <li class="ShortDesc" id="@items.ShortDesc">
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.ShortDesc').each(function () { 
            $(this).autocomplete({ 
                source: '/Cataloging/Bib/GetSubject',
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
            // Do something with "ui.item.Id" or "ui.item.Name" or any of the other properties you selected to return from the action
        }
    });
});
```

`$(Document).ready()` should happen after all the Razor Commands are finished

Comment: @KapsHasija  - ok , fix the code in your question , its hard to tell what is wrong with code that is written has other problems

Comment: I  am  using  "|a" indicators  from the starting. I need to  show  to  users "|a" that  indicators so they can  understand  what  to   write in input box..because  these  |a  indicators  can  be  changed to "b,c,v" what ever

Comment: @KapsHasija - edited answer - there were a couple more edits in there , that should work now

Comment: your  code  some  what  is  working  ..i  am  getting  my  data  but  its  not  binding  with  autocomplete

Comment: hit F12 in the browser and see what is being sent back ,see what is going into item.Name and what is going into ID ,  actually if you could copy and paste a sample of what is comming back from server side that would be good

Comment: yes  We  did...but  i  faced  another  problem   while  selecting  autocomplete  Text  i  missed  out  my  indicators "|a"..there  is  any  way  to  have  my  indicators  while selecting text from auto complete

Answer (score 0):

call a function every time after dynamically created an input

```
 create_dynaically(id);
```

this the function

```
function create_dynaically(id)
{

$("#"+id).autocomplete({   //this line
        source: '/Cataloging/Bib/GetSubject',
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // Do something with "ui.item.Id" or "ui.item.Name" or any of the other properties you selected to return from the action
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I just suggested that , he said that wasn't the problem ?? I don't know it sounds like it is??

Comment: I  think  i  need  to  use  Live..  but How  i  don't  know  with   this  code

Comment: @KapsHasija - you don't need .Live() or .On() , why don't you just post the code that creates the textbox dynamically , then we could show you how to add this in there